# HTTP Access to SQL Server Analysis Services from node.js

Tags: node.js, iis, ssas

http access to Analysis Services is possible using this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx.

Can we set up the same using node.js so that we can remove the dependency on IIS for a node.js application?

Comment: I came across this [xmla4js](https://github.com/rpbouman/xmla4js). see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible, except if you can access OLEDB data sources from node.js.

Low level XMLA access (proprietary MS protocol with some details on which Microsoft does not give access to without their permission) is the base of all access to Analysis Services.

Based on this low level, from Microsoft there is OLEDB, ADOMD.NET, AMO, and the http access you mention in your question. And as the low level interface is proprietary, It would be difficult for anybody else to implement another interface.

OLEDB and ADOMD.NET are query interfaces for the OLEDB or ADO.net specification. AMO is a .net interface to access (read and write) the structure of a cube, like the data source view, the dimension, measure group, or cube objects, or the calculation script. All these three interfaces are on a higher abstraction level than XMLA. And http access is just a kind of proxy bringing the XMLA interface to a documented level that can freely be used.

Thus, if you do not want to go the route of the official http access, and assuming you just need a query interface, you would have to use an environment that can either use OLEDB connections or can work with .net interfaces. I would think that both of these are not accessible from node.js. But I am not a node.js expert.